# Input hour and minute from user, and add duration to display updated time

Tags: c, time, printf

I need to write the program that accepts three integers as input (hour, minute, duration). Hour is in 24 hour format. The hour and minute should be considered the start time, and duration should be in minutes. You should then calculate the end time and display it properly in the format `##:##`. This is what I got but my Starting time displays weird.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int h=0,m=0,d=0,ht=0,t=0;
    printf("Starting Hours: ");
    scanf("%d",&h);
    printf("Starting Minutes: ");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    printf("Starting Time is %d,%d ,What is the duration");
    scanf("%d",&d);
    t=(m+d);
    ht=t/60;
    h=(h+ht)%24;
    m=t%60;
    printf("Ending Time: %d:%d",h,m);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

My starting time displays something like this: when I enter 12 for hours, and 52 for min my Starting time displays as

> -2114693200:1.

Not sure why happens

Comment: In `printf("Starting Time is %d,%d ,What is the duration");`, the arguments for the two `%d` are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

missing arguments in printf() causing undefined behaviour.

```
printf("Starting Time is %d,%d ,What is the duration");
```

it should be

```
printf("Starting Time is %d,%d ,What is the duration",h,m);
```

You also don't need to modulo by 24 unless you want to convert hour to days... if you want that you need to store and print number of days as well.

```
h=(h+ht)%24;
```

Comment: Duh! I missed it. Thank you.

Comment: I also have a question, how can I represent this problem using if and loop?

Comment: This is what my teacher what us to use, but I am not sure how to use if and loop in this problem as it can be written like I did (simply).

Comment: She probably wanted you to enable typing duration n times. So that the program asks you for the duration over and over again. Every time you type new duration, it adds to the last one and outputs the new time.

Comment: You can use while loop. And if is probably for checking if the duration is zero or something so it can break from the loop. If you are using while, there is no need for that, just check the variable used in while(variable != 0).

Comment: Not really, teacher desired output just to enter hour and minute and duration, and thats it

Comment: hmmm... in that case using loop seems overkill... may be she wanted to have ever running program which terminates after specific input..

Comment: I know, I am not sure myself. Maybe I should put limits for hour (not more than 24) and minutes not more than 60.

Answer (score 0):

You did not supply the arguments to the format specifiers in `printf()`. It invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1, *`fprintf()`*

> [...] If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is
>   undefined. [...]

You need to write

```
printf("Starting Time is %d,%d ,What is the duration", h, m);
```

That said, always check for the return value of `scanf()` to ensure the scanning is success.